# Change content in Footer in different section/page (Single Scroll Website)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I followed this jsfiddle provided by someone else (http://jsfiddle.net/U7d2y/54/). I wanted the information on the bottom left to change from social media icons present on the MENU and ABOUT page to a colophon information("web design by") on the CONTACT page.

However despite following the structure of the jsfiddle shown above, my code does not work, will be great if someone can help me to take a look. I am using twitter bootstrap as well. Thanks.

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kn02jvL3/14/ (Unfortunately not working)

HTML:

```
    <div class="footer">
        <p id="address">
            21 Road
        </a></p>

        <div id="nav">
            <span id="nav_link">(i)</span>
            <span id="nav_hover">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#menu">menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="footer_left">
            <ul>
                <li class="social_media" class="active"><a href="#menu">
                    <div class="facebook"></div>
                    <div class="twitter"></div>
                    <div class="instagram"></div>
                </a></li>
                <li class="social_media"><a href="#about">
                    <div class="facebook"></div>
                    <div class="twitter"></div>
                    <div class="instagram"></div>
                </a></li>
                <li id="colophon"><a href="#contact">Web Design by</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vertical-align">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 left-col">
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 content">

                <div id="menu">
                    <p class="menu_info">
                        The food </p>   </div>


            <div id="about">
                <p class="about_header">OUR RESTAURANT</p>
                <p class="about_info"> Latin (curare) stands for hospitality or “to take care of”, is headed by Chef-Owner Walsh, who has conceptualized a creative space where a seamless experience of top-notch food, drink and service is delivered in a casual yet refined environment.</p>
            </div>


            <div id="contact">

                <p id="hours">Opening Hours:<br>Mon-Sat:Dinner from 6:30pm<br>Thurs & Fri:Lunch from 12:00pm</p><br>

                <p id="add">Find Us at:<br>21 Road</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 right-col">     
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer_left li{
    display:none;
}

#footer_left li.active{
    display:block;
}

.social_media{
    z-index:5;
    display:block;

    position:fixed;
    margin-right:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    float:right;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
        $('body').scrollspy({ 
            target: '#footer_left' 
        });
```

Comment: fiddle is different with the code provided.

Comment: question is not clear.

Comment: What you asking is not clear.

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool the fiddle and the code provided is different, as I'm referencing the fiddle, and implementing my own code

Comment: @Era  I made an edit, is this more understandable? sorry if it wasnt clear before

Comment: create your your own code's fiddle. then only we can relate your question.

Comment: @Era please see jsFiddle

Comment: i think it is my scrollspy which is not working. not sure though